# how to posting array from a form?

Tags: php

**form 1 :**

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
     ....  
     echo "<td><input type='radio' value='".$data['jns']."' name='tes[".$data['kode]."]' /></td>";
     ....             
}
```

**form 2 :**

```
$kode = $_POST['tes'];
$temp[] = $kode;
$_SESSION['kd'] = $temp;
$jum_array=count($_SESSION['kd']);
for($i=0;$i<$jum_array;$i++){
    $nilai=$_SESSION['kd'][$i];
    echo $nilai;
}
```

the results do not display anything, only show posts "array".

Please help my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$nilai is not string, it is array:

```
$kode = $_POST['tes'];
$temp[] = $kode;
$_SESSION['kd'] = $temp;
$jum_array=count($_SESSION['kd']);
for($i=0;$i<$jum_array;$i++){
    $nilai=$_SESSION['kd'][$i];
    foreach($nilai as $k=>$v){
      echo  $nilai[$k] ;
      ///or echo $v;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to ask again.
for example i have  form 3 and form 4.
how do I display $nilai[$k] in form 3 and 4?

Comment: I am not getting your question..please explain in more details.

Comment: form 1 and form 2 as you can see above. if I want to create a new form, namely form 3. how do I display $nilai[$k] in form 3?

Comment: With the help of $_SESSION array?

Comment: Hopefully you are looking for this:

Comment: foreach($_SESSION['kd'] as $key=>$value)
{
 echo "<input type='radio' value='".$value."' name='tes[".$key."]' />";
                
}